# Reversing a commit in svn 1.7.4

Tags: svn

I tried the usual recipe to reverse-merge an unintended commit:

```
svn merge -rBAD_REV:BAD_REV-1 .
```

and was perturbed to get, as a response, merely a message about mergeinfo. No actual revert of file content to the previous rev.

I went and did the fix up in another tree where I could use svn 1.6.x, but  I ended up wondering: was it doing the right thing and not telling me, or has the recipe changed?

Answer (score 1):

That should still be correct, but try doing it from the top level of your source tree rather than in the directory of the file.  Alternatively try using the `--ignore-ancestry` flag to skip the warning about the mergeinfo (which shouldn't be a problem in your case unless someone happened to have created a branch from the BAD_REV revision).

Comment: I was at the top. I don't mind the merginfo warning, it's the lack of 'U' lines telling that it has, in fact, rolled anything back. And the fact that 'st' afterwards shows no modified files.